# WPF Data Binding ViewModel property to ListBox inside a User Control in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind dynamically, in code behind, a VM property (an obseravble collection) to image in listBox that sits inside a usercontrol I show on my window,
but it's not working.

This is the XAML of the user control:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="panel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False">
    <ListBox x:Name="MazeListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid x:Name="MazeUniformGrid" Columns="{Binding VM_MazeCols}" Rows="{Binding VM_MazeRows}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="Img" Margin="-6" Source="{Binding}" Focusable="False"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</WrapPanel>
```

This are the usercontrols in XAML of the Outer Window:

```
    <Controls:MazeBoard1  x:Name="you" Margin="0,0,650,0" Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Controls:MazeBoard1 x:Name="other" Margin="650,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This is how I bind dynamically in the cs of the window:

```
            Binding youBinding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("VM_MazeDisplay"),
        };

        Binding otherBinding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("VM_OtherMazeDisplay"),
        };
        you.MazeListBox.SetBinding( ContentControl.ContentProperty,youBinding);
        other.MazeListBox.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, otherBinding);
```

I'll appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks weird on your XAML...but if you do the following:
`you.MazeListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.DataContextProperty, youBinding)`
or
`you.SetBinding(UserControl.DataContextProperty, youBinding)`
or even `you.MazeListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, youBinding)` (you will have to remove the binding into your xaml).

You should have the expected results.

However, why doing a binding in this point and not just only setting the DataContext? Something like `you.DataContext = VM_MazeDisplay` (assuming the instance of the VM is called that way).

Also, why do you put your `ListBox` into a `WrapPanel`?

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you! All those were for further plan, but in the meantime it's what i got

Comment: Ok! Glad to have helped :)